# Was Zed Betrayed?

Tags: league-of-legends

Part of Zed's Lore reads:

> > The old man implored Zed to enter the temple, destroy the box, and lead his followers to balance. The dark ninja followed the master inside. Moments later, the assembled ninjas heard Zed cry out in pain. Mysteriously, he emerged unscathed, and threw the severed head of the master at Shen's feet. Screaming in rage, Zed commanded his followers to slaughter the master's students and seize the box.

This to me sounds like the master (the old man) betrayed Zed and attempted to slay him, only to slay one of his shadows instead (zed can make shadow images of himself), at which point Zed slays the master in revenge. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Zed's Lore in full: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/zed-master-shadows-revealed

Comment: Given that there is exactly one piece of zed lore available, and you linked to it, what exactly are you expecting to see in an answer?

Comment: @ravenDreamer If i knew for a fact that was the only peice of zed lore, do you think I would have asked the question? Do you guys, after all this time, think that little of me?

Comment: The issue is that this is speculative. You present "Zed's Lore in full" and then ask, "Is there more?", something that is nigh impossible to prove a negative of.

Comment: Often there **is** more, especially with League Lore. Perhaps on the forums. Perhaps on the wiki. There is huge chapters of what goes on in League that I don't pay attention to that other people do. I was hoping one of them could enlighten me

Comment: Tell ya what. I vtc. If an answer presents itself then someone can post that they know it and we can reopen the question. is that fair?

Comment: If you ever followed the awful lore rewrites recently, you wouldn't try to find any logic in the new lore - its almost at D3 level :(

Answer (score 0):

It feels like Zed did something which made him angry with himself. Maybe he killed his master or his master killed himself (*Seppuku*) as a reaction to Zed's decisions? After that he (Zed) went into a blind fury...

But as @**Blindy** quoted in [my earlier question about League of Legends lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91612/why-shouldnt-hecarim-trust-mordekaiser) Riot:

> We have developed an epic and comprehensive story for the shadow isles that we hope to fully explore in the future

So we will see in the future!

Comment: What does the shadow isles have to do with zed?

Comment: They want fullfil the LoL story and I'm pretty sure that few next characters are connected with Shadow Isles. But I might be wrong - we will see.